# What is the java "package private" equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

What is the java "package private" equivalent in C++ ? 
Java package privacy feature (where only classes within same package has visibility) is useful when providing APIs.

is there a similar feature for C++ (other than declaring other classes as "friend"s) ?
to elaborate more,
e.g. assume A.h and B.h are in same package (i.e. API lib)
File : A.h

```cpp
class A
{
public :
void doA();

private : 
 int m_valueA;
};
```

File : B.h

```cpp
class B
{
public : 
void doB()

private:
int m_valueB;

}
```

What I want is,

public visibility : ONLY A::doA() and B::doB()

within package(i.e. API lib) : A should be able to access B::m_valueB and B  should be able to access A::m_valueA.
**WITHOUT making each other "friend" classes.**

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java. Can you briefly explain what "Package Private" does, or is the explanation too long and wouldn't make sense to non-Java programmers?

Comment: @Kitswas: There are no more details to be provided. C++ has no such feature, or any feature like it. That's just how it is.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is it possible to emulate the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c++ doesn't have packages as in java. But it does have namespaces, however namespaces is just that, a `namespace`. So it is a different beast.

A somewhat emulation could in some situations be an inner classes (classes within other classes) - since inner classes are considered members.

Besides that, there are header files and implementation(.cpp files) - in that sense you have units or modules that control what is actual visible (not just private but completely hidden - *in particular if put into anon. `namespace`*). This concept covers both just a single .h file and .cpp file or entire projects/libs/dlls that is more like a full package (and can choose what parts of API they expose through what gets 'shown' in their respective header files).

Comment: @darune,Thanks. But "anonymous namespaces" is applicable only to a single file right ? So how can one achieve "...or entire projects/libs/dlls that is more like a full package" ?

Comment: @aKumara most traditional libs will have some internal parts (some header only libraries put internal things in a "private" or "internal" sub namespace in "*_impl.hpp" files - however there is no compiler enforced mechanism to prevent its use)

Answer (score 5):

C++ has no equivalent to the Java concept of a "package". A package in Java is an arbitrary collection of code, defined only by being collected together into a bundle.

As such, "package private" kind of makes a mockery of the concept of encapsulation. Yes, the scope of access is "limited" to some degree, but it remains largely unbounded. So it's probably for the best that this isn't a natural feature of the language.

While C++ does not offer the concept of a "package", there are ways to allow specific arbitrary bundles of code to call functions which other arbitrary bundles of code cannot. This requires the use of a "key type" idiom.

A "key type" is a (usually empty) type whose main feature is that only certain code can create objects of that type. Any function taking such a type as a parameter therefore can only be called by code that is able to create the key type. The type therefore "unlocks" the function; hence the name.

The traditional use for this is to allow forwarding of private access through `emplace` and similar perfect forwarding constructs in C++. The key type's default constructor is made `private`, and the only people who can create it are explicit `friend`s of the key type. But since the type is publicly copyable, any forwarding functions can copy them to the destination.

In your case, you want the key type to only be constructible from code in certain *files*. To do this, you simply have a header that provides a definition of the key type, typically as a simple empty class. In the public headers of your "package", any functions that you want to be "package private" will take a `package_private` as a `const&` parameter.

However, your public headers for the "package" do not include the *definition* of `package_private`; only a forward declaration of it. This means that code that only has access to the public headers are unable to create objects of that type. They can see the typename, but they cannot do anything with it.

So it might look like this:

```
//Internal header, included by all code in the "package"
struct package_private {};
inline constexpr static package_private priv; //Makes it easier to call these functions

//Header for library.
struct package_private;
void package_private_function(package_private const&, ...); //Must be `const&` to avoid needing to define `package_private`.

//To call the package private function inside the library:
package_private_function(priv, ...);

//This is a compile error for any code that doesn't have the internal header:
library::package_private priv{};
library::package_private_function(priv, ...);
```

C++ being C++, users can always *cheat*:

```
alignas(max_align_t) char data[sizeof(max_align_t)];
library::package_private &key = *reinterpret_cast<library::package_private*>(&data);

instance.pack_priv_function(key, ...);
```

This isn't even undefined behavior in C++20, so long as `package_private` is within the given alignment and size of `data` and it is an implicit lifetime type. You could do things that force `package_private` to not be these things, but that only renders this code UB. It will still compile and almost certainly still *work*; after all, the function isn't ever *accessing* this object.

The traditional way to hint to users that some type in a header is internal and shouldn't be used by external code is to stick it in a `detail` namespace.

C++20 modules provides a way to prevent a category of ways to subvert this. If we consider a module to be a "package", all you have to do is not `export` the `package_private` type. It can still be listed as parameters of functions that do get exported (and they no longer need to be `const&`). But the `package_private` type itself isn't exported.

Code within the module can use the name; you can put the definition into an implementation partition that gets `import`ed by any in-module files that need this access. But code outside of the module which `import`s it can't use that name, so they can't even do the casting trick shown above. There are metaprogramming techniques that *can* inspect a function's signature without knowing its types, but those are really hard and are spoiled by overloading.

Then again, Java reflection can break any encapsulation, so it's not like "package private" is fool-proof.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the PIMPL idiom in C++, which, as @darune said, is not equivalent but close in semantic. Typically, you'll do this:

In **YourPublicClass.hpp**

```cpp
class MyPublicClass
{
    // Public interface
public:
   void doSomething();
   
   void manipulatePrivateStuff(Stuff * stuff);

   MyPublicClass(...);
   ~MyPublicClass();

   struct Stuff;  // <= This is were the magic happens, this stuff 
                  //    is unknown/private from who include this header

private: 
   Stuff * _member;
};
```

In **YourPublicClass.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "YourPublicClass.hpp"

struct MyPublicClass::Stuff
{
    // Public members that are only accessible from this compilation unit
    // but private from the rest of the code, like a private package

    int a;
    
    void explodeInTenSeconds() { if (!a--) std::cout<<"Boom!"<<std::endl; }

    Stuff(int delay = 10) : a(delay) {}
};

void MyPublicClass::doSomething() { _member->explodeInTenSeconds(); }
void MyPublicClass::manipulatePrivateStuff(Stuff * stuff) { stuff->a = 10; }

MyPublicClass::MyPublicClass(...) : _member(new Stuff(10)) {}
MyPublicClass::~MyPublicClass() { delete(_member); }
```

If you need another class to access the "package private" Stuff, you'll to move the `MyPublicClass::Stuff` declaration to its own header and include that header in this class's definition file (`.cpp`). This header shouldn't be included outside of your "package", it's not public. It's not required to be manipulated, the compiler is perfectly fine with only knowing it's a pointer to a unspecified structure.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have packages.

The consequence is that the requested behavior "different access for other code inside my package from code outside my package" isn't even meaningful.  **There is no "code inside my package" because there is no "my package".**

Elaborating one step farther, the C++ `private` access modifier meets the specification of Java `package private`.  It's inaccessible (`private`) for code outside the package, just like Java `package private`.  And it is trivially accessible to code inside the same package --- because there is no such code.

Obviously that's not useful for establishing collaboration.  But it's what you get when you try to ask questions about C++ that are only meaningful in some other language.  Another aspect of your question that is Java-centric and harmful for thinking about C++, is that you consider all code to be organized into classes.  In C++ that isn't so, there are free functions and associated (by ADL) functions which are not class members.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It is important to understand what private-package is. It means that other members of the same package have access to the item. A package in java is an arbitrary collection of code which is defined only by being collected in bundle.
This feature of "private-package" in C++ has not equivalent to the java language.